# named cannot be loaded; because zone file errors

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I try to make a DNS server with named (I believe it is also called "BIND").

when I try to load the server I get:

```
 systemctl status named.service
* named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-02-11 18:03:56 IST; 6s ago
  Process: 20571 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

here is `/usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf`

```
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:1: unknown RR type 'prognoza.cu.cc.'
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:9: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:11: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:14: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:15: no TTL specified; zone rejected
zone prognoza.cu.cc/IN: loading from master file /var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone failed: unknown class/type
zone prognoza.cu.cc/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/prognoza.cu.cc/IN: unknown class/type
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
```

and `/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc`

```
OA     prognoza.cu.cc. (
        2013042201  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        3600       ;Minimum TTL
)
; Specify our two nameservers
                IN      NS              ns1.prognoza.cu.cc.
; Resolve nameserver hostnames to IP, replace with your two droplet IP addresses.
ns1             IN      A               31.220.108.9

; Define hostname -> IP pairs which you wish to resolve
@               IN      A               31.220.108.9
www             IN      A               31.220.108.9
```

I can't understand what is wrong.
I try first to make an A DNS record. 
Later I would like to add MX and PTR, but I haven't been managed to install the A record without errors.
My VPS runs on centos.
Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

After implementing Håkan Lindqvist's changes, I get these errors:

```
dns_rdata_fromtext: /var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:6: near eol: unexpected end of input
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:9: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:11: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:14: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:15: no TTL specified; zone rejected
zone prognoza.cu.cc/IN: loading from master file /var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone failed: unexpected end of input
```

Answer (score 2):

The first record would appear to be a messed up `SOA` record:

```
OA     prognoza.cu.cc. (
        2013042201  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        3600       ;Minimum TTL
)
```

Presumably you meant something like:

```
@ IN SOA     ns1.prognoza.cu.cc. hostmaster.prognoza.cu.cc. (
        2013042201  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        3600       ;Minimum TTL
)
```

Comment: don't you hate that, classic vi

Comment: okay now I get these:
dns_rdata_fromtext: /var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:6: near eol: unexpected end of input
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:9: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:11: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:14: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone:15: no TTL specified; zone rejected
zone prognoza.cu.cc/IN: loading from master file /var/named/prognoza.cu.cc.zone failed: unexpected end of input
zone prognoza.cu.cc/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/prognoza.cu.cc/IN: unexpected end of input

Comment: @prognoza Sorry, didn't pay attention to the other errors in the SOA record. Updated the answer.

Comment: what hostmaster.prognoza.cu.cc stands for? I would like that whenever a user enters prognoza.cu.cc it will be translated to my ip and he will be able to surf my site (an apache process listens to port 80, with the relevant domain which is prognoza.cu.cc).
Also, what is ns1.prognoza.cu.cc.?

Comment: @prognoza It's the email address of whoever maintains the zone. You could have a look at eg https://www.ripe.net/publications/docs/ripe-203 for some explanation and recommendations for the SOA fields.